# Wie sagt man "to do a root canal on someone" auf Deutsch?

Tags: grammar

> Ich gehe morgen zum Zahnarzt, um einen Wurzelkanal zu haben und Dr. Klaus wird an mir den Wurzelkanal machen.
>
> *I am going to the dentist to have a root canal. Dr. Klaus will perform the root canal on me.*

Wie sagt man: *to do a root canal on someone*?

Comment: I think it's "Doktor Klaus führt an mir eine Wurzelkanalbehandlung durch." Also, those two English sentences sound odd to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `Wurzelkanalbehandlung` in German.

> Dr. Klaus wird eine Wurzelkanalbehandlung durchführen.

Comment: Kann man so sagen `Doktor Klaus wird bei mir eine Wurzelkanalbehandlung durchführen` ?

Comment: Yes, that's absolutely correct.

Comment: Man sagt (außerhalb von Fachkreisen) nur [*"Wurzelbehandlung"*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Wurzelbehandlung). Das sollte unbedingt in dieser Antwort stehen!

Comment: Das hatte ich ursprünglich sogar geschrieben, aber die volle Bezeichnung scheint mir näher am englischen Original.